# How to redefine PATH variable with Docker command line on Windows

Tags: docker

I am running a Linux Docker image and need to define the PATH variable from a Windows host machine. I would like to use the docker command "exec" to update the PATH in my container.

I have tried the following:

```
docker exec -e PATH=${NEW_PATH_TO_ADD_TO_PATH_VARIABLE}:${PATH} _MY_CONTAINER_NAME_ env
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "env": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

What am I missing?

My Docker version is 20.10.12, build e91ed57

Comment: What's leading you to try this?  Any change you make this way will only affect the immediate `docker exec` debugging command.  In any case, the software built into the image is fixed, and if it's not in one of the "normal places" for software to be installed, its Dockerfile should use `ENV PATH=...` to update `$PATH`.

Comment: I am setting up a toolchain in the docker container that I can use to cross-compile source code. My goal is to use the container as a black box so I don't need to log in to do the cross-compilation. If I can update the PATH variable and set my toolchain in the container I can call the compiler from the host with docker exec _MY_CONTAINER_NAME_ _COMPILER_NAME_ ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `$PATH` variable inside a container has no relation to the `$PATH` variable on your host. Trying to prepend a new path to `$PATH` (in your example) will be evaluated in the shell from which you run the `docker` command, and take the `$PATH` variable from your host.

That said, Docker containers use a default `$PATH` (`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`), which is defined in the [`pkg/system`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a7ea29a5a6dcf65a2f4fff0be9becc2f7c587b4e/pkg/system/path.go#L3) package in the source code, so if you did not set a custom path on the container (and the image that the container was started started from didn't define a custom value), you can use that as a starting point, e.g.:

```sh
docker exec -it -e PATH "/some/new/path:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bi n" <your container> sh
```

As to the error you're getting:

```
"env": executable file not found in $PATH
```

This may depend on the image that your container was started from; it's possible that the container was started from a minimal image that may not contain the `env` binary, or may not even contain a shell, in which case you won't be able to use `docker exec` to get a shell inside the container.